# Getting error on GAE: Max number of files and blobs is 10000

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I am trying to migrate a Wordpress environment into a Google App Engine project. The current Wordpress environment is quite large. While deploying the files I get this error

```
11:42 AM Cloned 76000 files.
11:43 AM Cloned 78000 files.
11:43 AM Cloned 80000 files.
11:44 AM Cloned 82000 files.
11:45 AM Cloned 84000 files.
11:46 AM Cloned 86000 files.
11:47 AM Cloned 88000 files.
11:48 AM Cloned 90000 files.
11:49 AM Cloned 92000 files.
11:49 AM Rolling back the update.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Max number of files and blobs is 10000.
--- end server output ---
2015-10-24 11:49:07 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Can I get some help on how to overcome this and get my environment created on GAE?

Comment: Can you upload it as a zip file and then unzip it on the server?

Comment: that's not an option. The server is not writable like that.

Comment: Its not a programming problem. Its how do I package this application to suit the specific runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You're hitting the [Deployments quota](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Deployments).

Hm, a paid option to exceed the value doesn't seem to be available. 
Might be worthy to ask for it, per [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted):

> Is your app exceeding the default limits? If you have [Silver, Gold,
>   or Platinum support package](https://cloud.google.com/support/), you can [contact your support
>   representative](https://support.google.com/googleforwork/answer/142244?rd=1#cloud) to request higher throughput limits. Otherwise, you
>   can [apply for more Mail API quota](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dENESzEwNzJiZEdpQkRzTl9RNElVWUE6MQ#gid=0) or [file a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/)
>   for any other quota increase.

Meanwhile you could try to split your app in multiple modules and upload them separately (hoping that `app` really means `module` in the Deployments quota wording - versions really apply to modules, not to apps as a whole).

If splitting into modules doesn't work you could split the functionality into multiple apps, pointing to each-other to make them look more like a single app, potentially with nicely crafted custom sub-domain mappings. A nightmare, I'm not even sure I should be suggesting that :)

If the high number of files in the upload comes primarily from static content you could also consider serving some of that content from CDNs, separate apps or storing it in the GAE storage (practically limited only by the amount you're willing to pay) and serving it dynamically.