# Google App Engine too many files

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel-5, storage

I'm hosting a laravel site on google app engine and recently added and admin dashboard using frozennode's laravel-admin. Unfortunately it added A LOT of files and now I have gone over my limit for amount of files/blobs allowed (10,000). I have added as many unnecessary files to the skip files list in the app.yaml file as I could but I still exceed the limit.

The vendor file is where the bulk of the files are and I was wondering if there was a move the directory without compromising the functionality of the rest of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Removing unneeded files/dirs or moving them outside of the uploadable app code should not affect your app's functionality (but finding out which files are really unneeded may be tricky).

Removing needed files/dirs or moving them outside of the uploadable app code would break your app.

Moving files/dirs outside of the uploadable app code and symlink-ing them inside the uploadable app code won't make a difference since uploading the app automatically replaces the symlinks with their respective target content.

Assuming you can't remove enough unneeded files to no longer exceed the files quota this Q&A may help: [Getting error on GAE: Max number of files and blobs is 10000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319952/getting-error-on-gae-max-number-of-files-and-blobs-is-10000/33320363#33320363)