# Random Client Error (400) when deployment to GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am using NetBean to do developemnt. When I using GAE Launcher to deploy my php project to GAE, hit the following error:

```
10:57 AM Cloning 2898 static files.
10:57 AM Cloned 2000 files.
10:57 AM Cloning 3230 application files.
10:57 AM Cloned 2000 files.
10:57 AM Uploading 3 files and blobs.
10:57 AM Uploaded 3 files and blobs.
10:57 AM Compilation starting.
10:57 AM Compilation completed.
10:57 AM Starting deployment.
10:57 AM Rolling back the update.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
--- end server output ---
2015-11-12 10:57:59 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

Is it because of clone file limit? I realized I have to keep try deploy until no more sentence "Uploading x files and blobs.", then only can deploy successful.  How to I solve this? Thanks

Comment: it's not because of reaching the file limit, the error in that case looks like in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319952/getting-error-on-gae-max-number-of-files-and-blobs-is-10000/33320363#33320363

Comment: @DanCornilescu I realized I have to keep try deploy until no more sentence "Uploading x files and blobs.", then only can deploy successful.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I think I found an issue, Google is make some changes on server side. Because the Developer Console interface is changed, and no more deployment error by today.