# gcloud app deploy : This deployment has too many files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I got the below error, when I tried to deploy my GAE app through gcloud.

```
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                  
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [400] This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
      "fieldViolations": [
        {
          "description": "This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.",
          "field": "version.deployment.files[...]"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Is there any way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you really have more than the 10000 files quota in the service you're trying to deploy then you *might* have to reduce the number accordingly.

Other things to try:

- you *might* be able to get a quota increase, see [Getting error on GAE: Max number of files and blobs is 10000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319952/getting-error-on-gae-max-number-of-files-and-blobs-is-10000/33320363#33320363)
- delete whatever files are not actually needed, or just skip them during deployment see [skip_files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files) or, for the more recent cloud SDK versions, the [`.gcloudignore` file](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore).
- if you have a lot of static files consider moving (some of) them to GCS instead, see [Approaches for overcoming 10000 file limit on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176127/approaches-for-overcoming-10000-file-limit-on-google-app-engine/37176444#37176444)
- split the service into multiple smaller services - each with its own 10000 files limit.

Assuming you do not actually hit the files quota then the error usually indicates you have looping/circular referencing symlinks in your app directory. Which could also explain a path like the one you mentioned in a comment to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425048/4495081. You just have to fix the offending symlink(s). Again, a simple/consistent directory structure could help prevent such issues.

Comment: I tried adding to my list of skipped files in app.yaml, but whenever I did a deploy, this file was removed. I had not committed the change since its a global file, but I would have expected it to be used and preserved. How can I ensure it is being used? How do I tell what files are being downloaded by the deploy?

Comment: Dee Dave's answer below. Or use the [--verbosity](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity) option for [gcloud app deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy)

Answer (score 18):

`gcloud app deploy` writes a log file, and tells you where that log is early in its output. Examine that log. It'll tell you what's being uploaded.

Two common ways I've seen people get into trouble are

1. Using virtualenv, but not adding `venv` (or `.venv`, if that's the name you picked) to `skip_files`.
2. Using git, but forgetting to add `.git` to `skip_files`

Comment: For python runtime 3.7, this error is solved by adding these files to a .gcloudingore not to skip_files in the app.yaml

Comment: Adding a .gcloudignore file resulted in the error: ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) Cannot have both a .gcloudignore file and skip_files defined in the same application. We recommend you translate your skip_files ignore patterns to your .gcloudignore file. See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore for more information about gcloudignore.
 gcloud update failed. Bailing out

Comment: What is the syntax for the skip section in app.yaml? I want to have it skip my .tox directory but when I add the line: "- ^(.tox/), the deploy command reports a syntax error, and then it promptly overwrites my changes.

Comment: @ScottK https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files

Comment: Thanks @DaveW.Smith. How can I tell what these 10k+ files are, so I can start excluding them from the deploy? My change only has 4 files, so there must be a lot of extra files that I don't need.

Comment: @ScottK Post this as a question so that others can benefit from the answer. Nobody will ever see this if it's several comments in.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I have posted the question here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61112873/6693299

Comment: I have web app that contains 19k files , all is script files and folder what should I do or just app engine is made for small apps

Answer (score 5):

Maybe your need ignore some files in file .gcloudignore

```
/vendor/
/node_modules/
/.git/
```

This work for me!

Comment: I forgot to add `node_modules` to `.gcloudignore`. Oops.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in some comment, **virtualenv** folder can have a lot of files.

I just added `venv/` as a new line into `.gcloudignore` file.

Answer (score 1):

For python runtime 3.7, this error is solved by adding these files to a .gcloudingore not to skip_files in the app.yaml

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reduce my uploaded files by adding the google cloud sdk folder to .gcloudignore in the project root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

1. Sometimes the `static` folder can get a bit messy. Try deleting it and rerunning `python manage.py collectstatic`, this cut down about 2000 files for me.
2. Make sure your `.gcloudignore` file ignores the `assets` folder, given they've just been moved to `static`.
3. Ignore virtualenv folders, they're big

Answer (score 1):

I made a request to Google Cloud support, and this is their official response to this issue:

> Thank you for contacting Google Cloud Support. I understand you’re
> unable to deploy your app since you’re hitting a 10,000 file limit
> upload as indicated in the error message, let me know if I
> misunderstood.
>
> GAE is unable to perform deployments with over 10,000 files. Please
> run the following command to see the number of files being deployed:
> `find . -type f | wc -l`. In case you see that the number is above
> 10,000; make sure to prevent unnecessary files from being deployed by
> using the `app.yaml` option `skip_files` [1]. This element helps you to
> indicate which files should not be uploaded [1].
>
> If the error persists, there are two other ways to solve this problem:
>
> 1. If the files that you are using are static content, use Cloud Storage bucket to store your files. You can store them in a GCS bucket
>    and serve them through App Engine [2]. When you create an app, App
>    Engine creates a default bucket. To use it you will have to list the
>    bucket in your project [3] and then declare Cloud Storage as a
>    dependency by adding it to the app’s dependency files [4]. This will
>    allow you to upload or download data from the buckets [5][6]. Please
>    consider that using this alternative may impact your monthly expenses.
> 2. Increase the number of uploaded files by submitting a quota increase. To do so, I will require the following information which
>    will be submitted to the product team so they can review it and make a
>    decision on it: A business justification for this quota increase The
>    new desired limit.

1. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files
2. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-cloud-storage
3. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets
4. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#installing_the_client_library
5. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects
6. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Using .gcouldignore helped reduce from 15000 plus to 30.

```
 node_modules/
.gitignore
.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other answers, my problem was that `gcloud app deploy` does not ignore virtual envs or node modules.  The following helped me figure it out:

1. `gcloud meta list-files-for-upload` will show you the list of files that will be uploaded, without having to go through the deploy process.
2. Add the line:

   ```
   #!include:.gitignore
   ```

   to your `.gcloudignore` file, unless there are git-ignored files you want to upload.  You can't add `.gitignore` files from other directories, but this can get you a lot of the way there.
3. Add additional entries to `.gcloudignore` as needed until the list of files for upload is manageable.