# Google Appengine Error: Unable to update app: Applications are limited to 10000 files

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I am new to Google App Engine and I am having problem with deploying my application as I am getting the following errors

```
"SEVERE: Invalid character in filename: __static__/resources/js/morris.js-0.5.1/node_modules/gaze/test/fixtures/Project (LO)/one.js"

"com.google.appengine.tools.admin.LocalIOException: Applications are limited to 10000 files, you have 18867.
Unable to update app: Applications are limited to 10000 files, you have 18867."
```

The application has only 300 files and I am using eclipse neon. I have uninstalled eclipse and reinstalled it. I have deleted all the node modules in my local disk. I don't know from where the files are getting pulled.

When I searched the site one of the suggestions was to remove unwanted plugins. I looked at my Eclipse plugins, there are lots of them. I did not install anything, so I don't have any idea what to remove.

Eclipse Plugin window image
[image: Eclipse Plugin window image]

Is it a bug in eclipse or any configuration setting I have to take care? Please help.

Comment: What's your directory structure (including hidden files)?

Comment: @Dan Cornilescu I am using Maven to build my application. My application has 300 files. In "View Menu / Filters" of eclipse I have unchecked  "'.*resources " to show the hidden files. What exactly do you mean by "directory structure?" I am not clear.

Comment: Fundamentally the deployment step takes (some) files from your app directory (or even from outside that dir, as symlinks are followed) and uploads them to GAE. Regardless of what tooling you use at higher level. IMHO you should know exactly what happens at the base level.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451932/4495081

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

First, delete the parentheses in your directory name: `/Project (LO)/`

You will need to use `skip_files` to not upload any unnecessary files inside included packages.

Comment: I used< exclude path = " "/resources/**.js"  "/> files in appengine_web.xml. It reduced the file count significantly. Still the file count was above 10,000. Found I had included node server as part of my project in my resource directory. Once I removed it, the problem went away