# files limit in google cloud platform in angular universal project

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, angular-universal

Well, I am trying to follow some tutorial to deploy an Universal Angular project on google cloud platform.

The project work fine on local < it's just an empty Universal Angular project >.

So I try deploy it on google cloud app engine using:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

Here come the puzzle part: It gives me an error: 
`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000
      files for this app.
    field: version.deployment.files[...]`
Well, I am using the free plan from google:

So my question is:

- Is the google cloud platform try to upload all the files in the project folder of Universal Angular < which is huges because of node_modules folder>
- Is the google cloud platform limit the number of files to 10000? If so, how could I upload the universal project to google cloud platform? Do I have to upgrade my plan?

Thank you very much for reading the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcloud app deploy : This deployment has too many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451607/gcloud-app-deploy-this-deployment-has-too-many-files)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is because your node_modules folder is getting uploaded as well. There is a skip_files option for the app.yaml, which you might need to use to ensure that the node_modules directory isn't getting pushed.

[app.yaml docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref)