# gcloud app deploy : This deployment has too many files - How do tell what these 10k+ files are?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Follow up to [gcloud app deploy : This deployment has too many file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42451607/6693299) 
I am trying to deploy my App Engine Standard app to Google Cloud, but I get an error saying that I am trying to download too many files:

```
This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.
```

I have only changed 4 files, but it seems to trying to download a whole lot more.

How do I find out what these 10k files are that are being included in my deploy so I can start excluding them in my `skip_files` in `app.yaml`?

Comment: can you issue `ls -R` in the root of your project folder?

Comment: There are thousands of files under my root dir, but far less than 10k are required by the build that I am trying to deploy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
gcloud meta list-files-for-upload
```

This only takes into account your `.gcloudignore`, which you cannot use in conjunction with `skip_files`.

It is recommended that you translate your `skip_files` ignore patterns to your `.gcloudignore` file. See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore for more information about `.gcloudignore`.

Comment: In my environment, I have to use the skip_files section of app.yaml rather than .gcloudignore. Will this command take the skip_files list into account as well?